# Translating a html application to a C# application

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this question is short but there is nothing to say.

I found a nice html effect: 
https://codepen.io/jkiss/pen/OVEeqK

```
Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code
```

Can someone implement this in a borderless maximized winforms application?
Im not very good at programming in this kind. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Yes you can using Winforms or WPF.

Comment: You can make that with [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath) and a `Timer` that changes the drawn lines origin points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I made the assumption you wanted to write C# code *instead* of the HTML/css/js, and not host HTML in a WinForms application. Let me know if I was wrong)

Even though I think this question is way too broad for SO, here are some starting points:

- in WinForms you can paint on a form by overriding its `OnPaint` method
- if you clear the entire screen each frame in `OnPaint`, you should override `OnPaintBackground` and leave it empty
- call `SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true)` in the constructor of the form to avoid flicker
- the `Graphics` object that is provided for you in the `OnPaint` method can be used to draw lines and fill ellipses
- to keep your application responsive while having a decent framerate, you can call `Invalidate()` in your `OnPaint` method. This is faster than using a timer (although you won't get a *constant* framerate).

If you run into *specific* questions, SO is definitely the right place to go.

Comment: The OnPaint method is only called when I Alt+Tab to this window. How can I run the OnPaint method constantly

Comment: You could call `Invalidate()` from inside the `OnPaint` to do this. There are other methods, but this is by far the simplest while keeping a decent framerate.

Comment: If I do this, my background turns white. Make sure that I have a `BackgroundImage`